# Matching array elements from two tables and returning results in a new field with distinct values sharing at least one value using clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Hello I've two tables that share two fields, 'path' (single String field) and 'arrKW' (Array(String))

Exaple Table1

```
create table test (path String, arrKW Array(String))Engine=Memory as
select * from values (('folder/puntonet',['kw1','kw2']),
('folder/puntonet-2.0',['kw2','kw3']),
('folder/puntonet-4',['kw2','kw4']),
('folder/puntonet-5',['kw5','kw4']));



| path                  | arrKW       |
+---------------------+---------------+
| folder/puntonet     | ['kw1','kw2'] |
| folder/puntonet-2.0 | ['kw2','kw3'] |
| folder/puntonet-4   | ['kw2','kw4'] |
| folder/puntonet-5   | ['kw5','kw4'] |
```

Exaple Table2

```
create table test2 (path String, arrKW Array(String))Engine=Memory as
select * from values (('folder/otherpuntonet',['kw1','kw2']),
('folder/otherpuntonet-2.0',['kw2','kw77']),
('folder/otherpuntonet-4',['kw2','kw77']),
('folder/puntonet-5',['kw5','kw4']))


| path                    | arrKW           |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| folder/otherpuntonet     | ['kw1','kw2']  |
| folder/otherpuntonet-2.0 | ['kw2','kw77'] |
| folder/otherpuntonet-4   | ['kw2','kw77'] |
| folder/puntonet-5        | ['kw5','kw4']  |
```

Result  desired

```
| path                 | arrKW         | arrResult (from table2)                                                                                        |
+----------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| folder/otherpuntonet | ['kw1','kw2'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                                            |
| folder/puntonet-2.0  | ['kw2','kw3'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                     |
| folder/puntonet-4    | ['kw2','kw4'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4','folder/puntonet-5'] |
| folder/puntonet-5    | ['kw5','kw4'] | ['folder/otherpuntonet-4']                                                                       |
```

Answer (score 1):

task is very unclear

```sql
create table test (path String, arrKW Array(String))Engine=Memory as
select * from values (('folder/puntonet',['kw1','kw2']),
('folder/puntonet-2.0',['kw2','kw3']),
('folder/puntonet-4',['kw2','kw4']),
('folder/puntonet-5',['kw5','kw4']));

create table test2 (path String, arrKW Array(String))Engine=Memory as
select * from values (('folder/otherpuntonet',['kw1','kw2']),
('folder/otherpuntonet-2.0',['kw2','kw77']),
('folder/otherpuntonet-4',['kw2','kw77']),
('folder/otherpuntonet-5',['kw5','kw4']))

SELECT
    (arrayJoin(a) AS t).2 AS path,
    t.1 AS KW,
    t.3 as tab,
    arraySort(groupUniqArrayArray(patha)) AS result
FROM
(
    SELECT
        groupArray(pathx) AS patha,
        groupArray(t) AS a,
        arrayJoin(arrKW) AS KW
    FROM (select 'test' tab, null pathx, arrKW, (arrKW, path, tab) t from test union all 
          select 'test2' tab, path pathx, arrKW, (arrKW, path, tab) t from test2)
    GROUP BY KW
)
GROUP BY t
having tab = 'test'
ORDER BY path ASC

┌─path────────────────┬─KW────────────┬─tab──┬─result────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ folder/puntonet     │ ['kw1','kw2'] │ test │ ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                          │
│ folder/puntonet-2.0 │ ['kw2','kw3'] │ test │ ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                          │
│ folder/puntonet-4   │ ['kw2','kw4'] │ test │ ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4','folder/otherpuntonet-5'] │
│ folder/puntonet-5   │ ['kw5','kw4'] │ test │ ['folder/otherpuntonet-5']                                                                            │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

probably it can be improved

```sql
SELECT
    (arrayJoin(a) AS t).2 AS path,
    t.1 AS KW,
    arraySort(groupUniqArrayArray(patha)) AS result
FROM
(
    SELECT
        groupArray(pathx) AS patha,
        groupArray(t) AS a,
        arrayJoin(arrKW) AS KW
    FROM (select null pathx, arrKW, (arrKW, path) t from test union all 
          select path pathx, arrKW, ([], null) t from test2)
    GROUP BY KW
)
WHERE path is not null
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY path ASC

┌─path────────────────┬─KW────────────┬─result────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ folder/puntonet     │ ['kw1','kw2'] │ ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                          │
│ folder/puntonet-2.0 │ ['kw2','kw3'] │ ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4']                          │
│ folder/puntonet-4   │ ['kw2','kw4'] │ ['folder/otherpuntonet','folder/otherpuntonet-2.0','folder/otherpuntonet-4','folder/otherpuntonet-5'] │
│ folder/puntonet-5   │ ['kw5','kw4'] │ ['folder/otherpuntonet-5']                                                                            │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: sorry Denny, my english es very bad :(

tomorrow I've going describe best my problem.

Thanks very much for everything